# When using python-embedded version and doing pip install * it runs into a ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, python-embedding, termcolor

I am reflecting some python packages into .Net using https://github.com/henon/Python.Included, which relies on the python-embedded installation.

I enabled pip, which is not officially supported for python-embedded by following [this](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4207#issuecomment-281236055) method.

Now let's say my python executable is at this location `c:\users\a\appdata\local\python-3.7.3-embed-amd64\python.exe`.

I am trying to install tensorflow using the pip module of that python installation with:

```
c:\users\a\appdata\local\python-3.7.3-embed-amd64\python.exe -m pip install tensorflow
```

When I try to do this, it throws the following error while trying to install the `termocolor` tensorflow dependency:

```
Collecting termcolor>=1.1.0 (from tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8a/48/a76be51647d0eb9f10e2a4511bf3ffb8cc1e6b14e9e4fab46173aa79f981/termcolor-1.1.0.tar.gz
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\a\appdata\local\python-3.7.3-embed-amd64\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\a\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-b_b76a7_\\termcolor\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\a\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-b_b76a7_\\termcolor\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
         cwd: C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-b_b76a7_\termcolor\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-b_b76a7_\termcolor\setup.py", line 35, in <module>
        from termcolor import VERSION
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'termcolor'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I tried to use my local python installation I previously had via miniconda and ran the command `pip install tensorflow` on the base environment and it went ok.

I don't understand what is happening, does anybody have a clue?

Comment: I think python 3.7 is not supported yet. Try another version backwords.

Comment: Build a wheel with the non-embedded version of Python and install this instead.

Comment: @KostasCharitidis do you mean that tensorflow does not support python 3.7 yet?